# Apollo GraphQL, when fetching typeerror: is undefined

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I'm new to GraphQL, I can't figure out why when I request to get data, for example `data.category.products`, I get the correct output, but for example, if I request `data.category.products.prices`, I will get this error: *TypeError: data. category.products.prices is undefined*

My Query:

```
query AllCategory{
  category {
    products {
      id
      prices {
        currency {
          label
        }
        amount
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Doesn't give errors in Playground

Here is the schema:
[image]

And actually how I call: (this is with an error)

```
export default function App() {

   const {data} = useQuery(QUERIES)

   return (
    
     <div className="App">
       {data.category.products.prices.map((shop) => (
         <p key={shop.currency.label}>{shop.amount}</p>
       ))}
     </div>
   );
}
```

There is no error here:

```
{data.category.products.map((shop) => (
   <p key={shop.id}>{shop.id}</p>
))}
```

I`m using apollo client

Comment: did you null check ``data` first..  the call is async

Comment: don`t get the question, can you describe it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Products and prices are both arrays so you will need to flatten it or map first through your products and then through your prices.

I'd break off a component or 2. .It's not clear if you want to render product level stuff. but it would be something along these lines:

```
const Product = (product) => (
  <>
    {product.prices.map((price) => (
      <p key={price.currency.label}>{price.amount}</p>
    ))}
  </>
);

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {data.category.products.map((product) => (
          <Product product={product} />
        ))}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

I'd also recommend you generate a type safe graphql schema so that you can pick up on type issues at compile time.

You also want to ensure that `data` is not null by doing a truthiness check before returning as its an asynchronous call - `data` is defined once the  graphql response is made.
e.g..
`return !data?null:<>......</>`

`useQuery` also returns `loading` and `error` values from the hook which are useful

Comment: So, I checked, the same error

Comment: Now I`m getting error, that price.currency is not defined

Comment: Now this error: TypeError: can't define property "map": Array is not extensible
(annoying thing)

Comment: you will need to manually define the shape of your proptypes using proptypes if javascript or interfaces if using Typescript. I recommend you generate a schema though

Comment: Ok, now I have this error: ``Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`` And I really appreciate your answers, they are getting me closer and closer to the result.

Comment: hard to tell what your code looks like now, but the error message is fairly self explanatory

Comment: So, I changed App into a function and error now is TypeError: data is undefined

Comment: do a null check on data when returning: `return !data?null: (<>...... the rest`

Comment: Somehow work, I appreciate your efforts